# Fill data frame by row with a nested for loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, analytics, nested-loops

I am trying to use R to fill a dataframe with a nested for loop. See description below.

I created an empty dataframe with the ID number of each subject within a study I am doing which look like this:

> ```
>       ID      X0     X1     X2
> 1     345     NA     NA     NA       
> 2     378     NA     NA     NA      
> 3     395     NA     NA     NA      
> 4     401     NA     NA     NA
> ```

From before do I have a dataset with the subject ID and respons time pr day from day 0 to day 2 in a column. Here each ID is represented three times with a respons time from day 0 to 2 for each subject. The data table looks like this:

> ```
>       ID    Respons Time   
> 1     345     24.5       
> 2     345     34.7        
> 3     345     34.6       
> 4     378     23.6     
> 5     378     76.4         
> 6     378     27.6      
> 7     395     24.3       
> 8     395     24.0        
> 9     395     56.4      
> 10    401     34.5        
> 11    401     23.5       
> 12    401     45.7
> ```

My goal is to use a nested for loop to fill the empty dataframe above with the values that belong to each ID on each row, so it look like this:

> ```
>       ID      X0     X1     X2
> 1     345     24.5   34.7   34.6       
> 2     378     23.6   76.4   27.6      
> 3     395     24.3   24.0   56.4      
> 4     401     34.5   23.5   45.7
> ```

I have tried to express this with a nested for loop without luck, and I feel I miss something to fill the data the right way in the Empty data frame illustrated above.

```
subjectUnique <- sort(unique(data$ID))
Empty_df <- data.frame(ID=subjectUnique, X0=NA, rbind(rep(NA, 2)))
n <- length(subjectUnique)
for(i in (1:n)) {
  for(j in (0:2)) {
    Empty_df[i,j+2] <- **I am not sure what I can put here to get this to work?** 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can reshape to 'wide' from the second data itself by creating a sequence column (`rowid`) from the 'ID' column and then use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
 df2 %>% 
    mutate(cn = str_c("X", rowid(ID))) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = cn, values_from = ResponsTime)
# A tibble: 4 × 4
     ID    X1    X2    X3
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   345  24.5  34.7  34.6
2   378  23.6  76.4  27.6
3   395  24.3  24    56.4
4   401  34.5  23.5  45.7
```

---

If we want a `base R` loop

```
 for(id in df1$ID) df1[df1$ID == id, -1] <- df2$ResponsTime[df2$ID == id]
```

-output

```
> df1
   ID   X0   X1   X2
1 345 24.5 34.7 34.6
2 378 23.6 76.4 27.6
3 395 24.3 24.0 56.4
4 401 34.5 23.5 45.7
```

#### data

```
df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(345L, 345L, 345L, 378L, 378L, 378L, 395L, 
395L, 395L, 401L, 401L, 401L), ResponsTime = c(24.5, 34.7, 34.6, 
23.6, 76.4, 27.6, 24.3, 24, 56.4, 34.5, 23.5, 45.7)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(345L, 378L, 395L, 401L), 
  X0 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA), X1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), X2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't want to use a package, I am trying to get better with nested for-loops and I want to do this with a loop even tho there are other options

Comment: @Delusion989 Do you only want to use `nested loop` or are you okay with `base R` solutions?

Comment: @Delusion989 i updated with a loop